# Find precise timezone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have been trying to find the precise timezone of the user. I have used the following code:

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();
console.log('Your timezone is: ' + timezone.name());
```

but problem comes when two or more zones have same UTC. For ex:

```
(UTC+09:00) Seoul
(UTC+09:00) Tokoyo
(UTC+09:00) Yakutsk
```

Say my time zone is Yakutsk but it may return:

`"Asia/Tokyo"`

The above code works fine in chrome but in Mozilla & IE, it fails to give precise timezone. Is there any way get the precise timezone of the client using JS?

Comment: clearly `jstz` isn't worth using ... firefox natively tells me **GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)** - the only thing wrong with that is that it's Daylight Saving Time at the moment

Comment: How is the browser supposed to know what exact time zone you're in? You may even need to use the geolocation api if you want to get the right name.

Comment: The short answer is - *you can't*.  The longer answer is in the dup question, but no approach is currently foolproof.  Eventually the `Intl` API will be widespread and then you can rely on it, but there is no *precise* option for now.